# How to rename folders with a converted date format?

Tags: gnu

They're named with `date '+%d-%m-%Y, %a, %k.%M.%S'`. I'm looking to rename them to `date '+%Y-%m-%d, %a, %H.%M.%S'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `prename` command:

```
prename 's/^(..)-(..)-(....)/$3-$2-$1/; s/  / 0/' [list of files]
```

This will capture the day, month, year and rewrite it in year, month, day order. Then it will take all occurences of double spaces (which only occurs before the hour, and only it hour is <10, when formatted with %k) and transform it to " 0", which in practice makes it equivalent to %H.

`prename` is a Perl script included in most standard Perl installations (in my experience) and is thus probably already present on your system. It is often (e.g. on Debian based systems) linked to `rename`.

Use the `-n` (`--no-act`) switch to `prename` the first time you run it to only show what changes will be done when the switch is removed.